# Installing 3 Operating Systems

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Edubuntu all as if I were dual-booting, except I suppose it would become tri-booting. How should I go about doing this ? Are there any special steps involved other than simply installing them ? I install them via USB, by the way. I have also just tried dual-booting and Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Edubuntu all won't detect each other when I get to the Installation Type screen in the installation

Comment: Is this because you want to compare the versions in some manner?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: if you want to compare them the EASIEST method is to install 1 OS (your main) and then use VirtualBox to install the others.

Comment: Aside from performance issues, it may be much easier to do this in virtual machines.

Comment: @Rinzwind  Great minds...

Comment: What would the hard method be ?

Comment: Getting them to do triple boot.  I use VirtualBox (I use the Oracle PPA for this) and am running WinXP,7, 8.1, Android, and a test Ubuntu.  While my main Ubuntu remains stable, I can play to my hearts content in the virtual machines.

Comment: The hard way: install all 3 in separate partitions. Well it is not that hard but grub needs to play nice from the get go ;) did it have windows 8 on it? if so: check BIOS and disable fast booting.

Comment: It originally had Windows XP, but that's long gone. I have disabled fast booting a few minutes ago though and am trying it now

Comment: Would using Unetbootin to put the operating systems on flash drives be easier ? I simply used startup disk creator with iso files I got from the download sites

Comment: There is software out there that can just boot all three from a USB stick. http://www.pendrivelinux.com/tag/boot-multiple-isos-from-flash-drive/

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't automatically being detected, you may have to turn UEFI boot mode and/or Secure Boot off. When your computer first boots you should see an option to go into the UEFI and change these.

You may also select "Something else..." and manually set up your partitions.

Comment: I don't see anything about UEFI. At startup, the BIOS tells me F2 for setup and F12 for boot menu. I've already been to setup and saw nothing UEFI and the only boot menu option I haven't tried is Boot to Utility Partition

Comment: Okay, then manually setting up your partitions would be the way to go... see http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: What do I do if I'm running Ubuntu already, instead of windows or a blank disk like it is listed ?

Comment: Unless you can tell me how to make a blank disk

Comment: @Mr.Stark You can still access the "something else" menu, create three etx4 partitions for each system, and one swap partition [of decent size](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

Comment: Will all of them use the same swap partition then ?

Comment: I have 3 partitions made in ext4 format and one partition made in linux-swap format. When I press Install Now, a message pops up saying "No root file system is detected. Please correct this from the partitioning menu."

Comment: You have to select the desired partition and click "Change...", then make sure the mount point is simply `/`.

Comment: Should all the partitions be mounted at /

Comment: Just the one that you want to install on. Do this for each Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just install them normally to separate partitions, they will automatically update grub to include all usable systems